# how to respond to a key press when focused on a radiogroup in delphi

Tags: delphi, radio-group, onkeypress

In delphi:
How can you respond to a key press when the current focus is on a radiogroup which does not have an onkeypress event. I was hoping to use the forms onkeypress event but it doesnt see to fire.

Comment: Assuming your form is a VCL form, just set the form's `KeyPreview` property to `True`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make this possible by setting the form's [`KeyPreview`](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/Libraries/en/Vcl.Forms.TCustomForm.KeyPreview) property to `True`.

However, I'm not sure you are actually doing things right, since this is a fairly uncommon problem.

You didn't write what keyboard shortcut you want to respond to. But please remember that

- Letters are used to navigate the GUI. For instance, pressing `A` might select the `&All` radio button or click the `&Add` push button. Similarly, `Alt+A` does the same if the current control allows character input, allows you to open the `&Add-ons` menu item, etc.
- If you want to add a proper shortcut like `Ctrl+O`, it is much better to use a `TActionList` with an action having this shortcut. This action can be mapped to menu items, buttons, etc., or simply exist in the background not being attached to any visual control. In very simple applications, you might want to use a stand-alone menu item with such a shortcut instead.

Comment: I only want to respond to an ENTER press to continue onto next item

Comment: @TonyWolff: Okay. Within the same dialog box, I assume. (Just for the benefit of other visitors to this page that may want to do something else: to make Enter activate the "Close", "Next >", or "OK" button, make that button `Default = True`.)

Comment: I don't have any buttons on the form apart from a save and a cancel button. Furthermore the next component requiring focus depends on the response to the current item.